# Create copy of function with some parameters fixed

Tags: function-construction

I know that, given a function `f[x_,y_] := x + y` I can set `g[x_] = f[x,2]` and evaluate `g[3] = 5`.

But given I have a function `h[g_,3] := g[3]` can i somehow pass `f[x,2]` directly as `g` to `h`? if so how?

Answer (score 3):

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y
h[g_, 3] := g[3]
h[f[#, 2] &, 3]
```

But describe your problem in more detail.  There is almost certainly a better solution ...

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for. The application requires quite a bit of explanation but put shortly, assume that h is a dyamic system and f an optimization function that returns the input to the system. the system will feed necessary input information to the optimization procedure however I also want to parameterize the optimization procedure on a parameter that i set outside the scope of h.